# Customized RatingBar in Android does not change color of icon

Tags: android, ratingbar

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Does anybody know what needs to be changed in order to add a different color to the active icon?

Here is what I tried:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/myYellow</item>
</style>
```

This changes the color to yellow (that is what I would like to do), but it leaves a green shadow/boarder on the left side. There seems to be a slightly misplaced icon beyond my yellow star? See result:

[image]

I also tried this, but it showed no effect:

```
<style name="RatingBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">#f00</item>
    <item name="android:colorControlActivated">#0f0</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Have you set `android:theme="@style/RatingBar"` in xml ? Also Let us know the API level you are testing on .

Comment: Got it: I didn't set the theme correctly (instead I used `style="@style/RatingBar"`). It is now looking super fancy. Thank you!